# Why do I get a Lexer error while preprocessing my AngularJS template with ng-html2js

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, ng-html2js

I'm trying to write a unit test for an AngularJS directive using Karma.
To be able to use the directive's template in the test I use [karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor).

For the following template HTML I get a Lexer error message in the unit test, but in the real system everything works fine.

```
<div class="test"
    ng-style="{width: vm.width,
    height: vm.height,
    'margin-left': vm.x,
    'margin-top': vm.y}">
</div>
```

Error message:

> Error: [$parse:lexerr] Lexer Error: Unexpected next character at
>   columns 17-17 [] in expression [{width: vm.width,\n' +
>             '   height: vm.height,\n' +
>             '   \'margin-left\': vm.x,\n' +
>             '   \'margin-top\': vm.y}].

Is this a bug in the preprocessor or is there a problem with my expression ?

Comment: can we see the original expression?

Comment: @dayan-moreno-leon: What do you mean by "original expression"? Isn't the value of the ng-style attribute the expression? Sorry, I'm an AngularJS newbie..

Comment: it seems, that it doesn't like the \ character

Comment: Looks like it doesn't like the newline character. Try without newlines inside `ng-style`.

Comment: @tassekatt Tried it, but then the <pre>\'</pre> causes the same problem. It really seems to be the \ escape character, added by ng-html2js.

Comment: @MarkusE. I have a similar problem (using `ng-show="myproperty == 'somevalue'"`), any workaround? thanks

Comment: @juliocesar I ended up doing it in a similar way as you provided in your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got similar problem, but I didn't found how to solve it. Nevertheless I found a way to avoid it.

I think the problem is on using single quotation marks (`'`), when *ng-html2js-preprocessor* process templates, single quotation marks are escaped using `\'`.

So in your case you need to avoid using quotation marks in `ng-style` value. i.e. by define a scope for it in a controller or other place:

```
$scope.mystyle = {
    width: vm.width,
    height: vm.height,
    'margin-left': vm.x,
    'margin-top': vm.y
}
```

Then use it in tour attribute:

```
<div class="test" ng-style="mystyle"></div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: That's how I eventually did it. It is a work-around, but seems to be the only valid answer right now.